# Creating 1 to Many relationships in Ember Data - Best Practice

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

We have successfully implemented 1 to many relationships in our project, but I am not sure that our implementation is best practice. Our current setup is detailed below:

```
Contact Model:
name: DS.attr('string'),
telephones: DS.hasMany('telephone', { async: false}),

Telephone Model:
number: DS.attr('string'),
contact: DS.belongsTo('contact', { async: true}),
```

Note: async is false on telephones as we sideload it with the contact.

The following code is used to save a new contact with a telephone number:

```
ContactController:
var newContact = this.get('model').createRecord('contact');
newContact.set('name', 'John');

var newTel1 = this.get('model').createRecord('telephone');
newTel1.set('number', '555-1234');
newContact.get('telephones').pushObject(newTel1);

var newTel2 = this.get('model').createRecord('telephone');
newTel2.set('number', '555-6789');
newContact.get('telephones').pushObject(newTel2);

newContact.save().then(function() {

   var telephones = newContact.get('telephones');
   telephones.forEach(function(telephone){
      telephone.set('contact', newContact); 
      telephone.save();
   });
});
```

This code did not work initially as the server response to the contact POST had an empty array for telephones (as telephones had not been saved on the server yet). This caused ember to set the telephones relationship of the contact to null and the forEach loop after the contact save therefor had 0 elements. All telephones were lost. We then fixed it by creating a contact serializer:

```
extractCreateRecord: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {

    delete payload.contact.telephones;    
    return this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
},
```

After implementing the serializer, we can now successfully save a new contact with telephone numbers. However, this does not intuitively feel like the best solution - was this the best way to proceed or can be be doing things better?

We are using the RestAdapter and are on Ember 1.9. Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.12 and Handlebars 2.